# how to configure canvas and scrollbar settings to allow a scrollable region containing buttons in TKinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas

Pretty new to tkinter and python in general. I am trying to create a scrollable canvas to insert buttons and image labels because the page would be too short otherwise. the scroll region works well when I don't have buttons and images in it, but when I add them it just expands to fit them and the scrollbar disappears. I think it's happening because the container is growing to fit the children buttons and labels. Idk how to change it so it ignores this? I've tried using both the canvas and frame as parent to the buttons. What else can I do to make this work the way I want?

> Background, canvas, and ybar settings

```
root=Tk()

background_photo = PhotoImage(file="imageSMALL.png")
background = Label(root, image=background_photo, bg="black")
background.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
frame=Frame(background, width=300, height=300)
frame.grid(row=0,column=0)
canvas=Canvas(frame,bg='#FFFFFF',width=300,height=300,scrollregion=(0,0,500,500))
vbar=Scrollbar(frame,orient=VERTICAL)
vbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
vbar.config(command=canvas.yview)
canvas.config(width=300,height=300)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
canvas.pack(side=LEFT,expand=True,fill=BOTH)
```

> Example of the many buttons and label images I want to add

```
ixalan_photo = PhotoImage(file="ixalan.png")
ixalan_img = Label(canvas, image=ixalan_photo, bg="black")
ixalan_img.pack(side=TOP)
ixalan_but = Button(canvas, text="IXALAN BLOCK", font=("Helvetica", 8), fg="white", bg="black", command=test)
ixalan_but.pack(side=TOP)

hour_photo = PhotoImage(file="hour.png")
hour_img = Label(canvas, image=hour_photo, bg="black")
hour_img.pack(side=TOP)
amonkhet_photo = PhotoImage(file="amonkhet.png")
amonkhet_img = Label(canvas, image=amonkhet_photo, bg="black")
amonkhet_img.pack(side=TOP)
amon_block_butt = Button(canvas, text="AMONKHET BLOCK", font=("Helvetica", 8), command = test, fg="white", bg="black")
amon_block_butt.pack(side=TOP)
```

Your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you make your examples so that they can be run standalone to see the problem?

Comment: You have to use `canvas.create_window` rather than `pack` or `grid` for something to be scrollable on a canvas.

Comment: @Nae Not at home near my computer atm. Still new to this site, I'll update when I get back.

Comment: @BryanOakley Awesome, I'll try doing that. Once I create a window, I'm assuming I can add the buttons as a child of the canvas.create_window and that alone should fix the problem? Thanks for the help by the way :)